# ViewPager setOffscreenPageLimit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My `ViewPager` with `setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` is retarding when user scrolling fragments. I was set `setOffscreenPageLimit(8)` (maximum limit of pages) `ViewPager` became scrolling smoothly but `Activity` with this `ViewPager` became loading more than 3 seconds. Can anyone prompt me how to solve this problem?

---

### TraceView

Traceview showed that a lot of time is going on the following blocks of code:

```
    View infoView = LayoutInflater.from(holder.viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.info_view, holder.viewGroup, false);
    TextView info = (RobottoRegularTextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.subject_audience);
    info.setText("some text");
    holder.someView.addView(infoView);
```

Also 36% of time is going on `Typeface.nativeCreateFromAsset()`

Comment: Use Traceview and figure out where you are taking your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare, maybe there is a way to set setOffscreenPageLimit(8) after Activity completely loaded?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm now trying to somehow circumvent this bug. I seted ViewPager Visibility.GONE to disallow onCreateView method and add loading image. Then I send new postDelayed Handler with Runnable wich sets ViewPager's Visibility.VISIBLE  to boost Activity loading time, but when Runnable starts all animations are freeze. Can U suggest something?

Comment: I would suggest that you use Traceview to figure out where you are taking your time, then fix your code to take less time on the main application thread there.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I did it and update my question. But I dont know how to modify the following code to make my program launch faster. If I will delete that my program will loose the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also 36% of time is going on Typeface.nativeCreateFromAsset()

Did you write `RobottoRegularTextView`? If yes, fix it to use a single `Typeface` rather than creating new ones for each instance of the widget. If not, switch to some other library for providing you with a `TextView` with an associated `Typeface` (e.g., [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)), or just handle the `Typeface` yourself in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Thank U very much ))) I solve my problem + I know now how to work with TraceView )))